# Run a command line with c++

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I have read several posts about running a command line in c++, but none of them does what I want  : no display of the console in an external application when I use the dllfile.

My problem :  I want to use a process that picks files from a database. For example : to get a file XYZ.xyz and copy it to the directory MyDirXYZ, I would use the command line 
"MyDataGenerator XYZ.xyz C:\MyDirXYZ".

**I use Visual studio** 
Let 's take the following example to clarify the issue, I am trying to create a directory with "mkdir" in C++ , without using CreateDirectory :

First method  :

```
std::string lDirectory("c:\\MyDummyDir")
std::string lCmd("mkdir " + lDirectory);
system((lCmd).c_str());
```

It will work , however **it displays the console** when I run it with a dllfile on Excel .

Second Method ( convertToRightFormat() convert a char to a TChar)

```
    std::string lDirectory("c:\\MyDummyDir")
    std::string lCmd("mkdir " + lDirectory);
    BOOL _status = TRUE;
    DWORD _reply, _code;
    STARTUPINFO _si = { sizeof(_si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION _pi;
    TCHAR *_cmd = NULL;
   _cmd=convertToRightFormat(lCmd.c_str())
   _status &= CreateProcess(NULL, _cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &_si, &_pi);
```

This method does not work(not even creating the folder) , and obviously it does not work either for the process "MyDataGenerator".

I tried to use the executable MKDIR.EXE and put it in the commandline. In that case, it works , but still does not work for MyDataGenerator.

Is there a generic to make all command lines work, without showing the console?

Thanks you.

Comment: Maybe you should check out Boost Filesystem http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#exists

Comment: You have nearly full control via `CreateProcess`. Note that `mkdir` is not an executable. It's an internal command in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to use `TCHAR` and stuff, since about 16 years ago.

Comment: I want to avoid using Boost. According to what I read, I thought CreateProcess would solve the issue, but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: How to mimic an internal command in c++ ?

Comment: @Canardini: You don't mimic it. You can use `cmd /c mkdir ...` as command line to execute, or you can use a Windows API function to create the directory.

Comment: That is what I am talking about, it works. Now I am gonna try with excel and the Dll . In the meantime, can you write an answer so I can vote for it ?

Comment: You have to put @username to make sure that person sees your comment.

Comment: Thanks, @Cheersandhth.-Alf please read above

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h> // FreeConsole, system

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    system("mkdir newdirectoryname");
    FreeConsole();
}
```

This will result in cmd popping up for a split second though. It closes after that.

If thats not acceptable just target the windows subsystem instead of the console one and make sure to not draw the window.